# How do two lists share the same object？

Tags: java

There is an object named position;
There are two ArrayLists named list1 and list2;

I want to add the position into the two lists.
How can I change the position in list1 to affect the position in list2？

Comment: And what have you tried? Is it not working?

Comment: If you add the object to both arraylists, then both arraylists will reference the same object.  It does not matter if you access the object through list1 or list2, it's still the same object.

Answer (score 4):

If you add the same Position object into both lists, than any changes you make to one will apply to the other as well, because they are the same object and therefore point to the same memory address.

For example, consider the object Position with x and y properties:

```java
Position p1 = new Position(0,0); 

ArrayList<Position> positions_1 = new ArrayList<Position>();
ArrayList<Position> positions_2 = new ArrayList<Position>();
ArrayList<Position> positions_3 = new ArrayList<Position>();

positions_1.add(p1);
positions_2.add(p1);
positions_3.add(p1);

System.out.println(p1.toString());     //X = 0, Y = 0
System.out.println(positions_1.get(0); //X = 0, Y = 0
System.out.println(positions_2.get(0); //X = 0, Y = 0
System.out.println(positions_3.get(0); //X = 0, Y = 0

p1.setX(1);
positions_1.get(0).setY(1);

System.out.println(p1.toString());     //X = 1, Y = 1
System.out.println(positions_1.get(0); //X = 1, Y = 1
System.out.println(positions_2.get(0); //X = 1, Y = 1
System.out.println(positions_3.get(0); //X = 1, Y = 1
```

Explanation: as all lists share the same object `p1`, if any changes happen to it, all lists will have this object modified, because "behind the scenes" there is only one object whose reference is being used in different places.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a slight wording change.  This answer sounds like if you make a change to the object, it will affect the lists.  This is not true, because the lists only contain a reference to the object.  The object is the only thing that is changed, the lists are not affected.

Comment: @Pedro Accorsi, Thank you very much, I know it.